# How to disable direct push to Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

While working with Gerrit, the expected `push` is:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

But some bad guys seems to do this in a simple way(they learned from some Git manual):

```
git push origin
```

or

```
git push
```

These operation will cause serious problems:

- The commit merged directly into master (or some default) branch in remote server.
- Although the guys write some commit message, but `git log` can'not find them.
- Maybe more...

Is there was a way to disable these `push` operation in Gerrit settings? Or disable it in client?

Answer (score 6):

There are permissions in the Gerrit admin UI. Permissions are inherited from the `All-Projects` project. Have a look there (Admin => Project => All-Projects => Access) and remove the push right to anyone on master. More details in the doc here: [Access control](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push)

Comment: I mean most of the time, people are `push` to `refs/for/master`. But if one do not type `HEAD:refs/for/master`, the commit will automatically merged into master and there was no log recorded. That's the problem.

Comment: if you prevent push right onto `master` but allow on `refs/for/master`, then you problem will be solved