# successful git push not displayed in Gerrit interface

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push

I'm unable to display changes that I successfully pushed to a Git server in the Gerrit web site. I used these commands to push my changes:

```
git commit -a
git push
```

but I can't found any changes in the Gerrit website interface.

Comment: Did you push to e.g. `refs/for/master` ?

Comment: It's also a permission issue. Commits can make it through without review. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654184/how-to-disable-direct-push-to-gerrit for details on how to block it.